# EJB in REST service returns null pointer exception

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I'm trying to implement REST service with Resteasy and Jboss as7, I have session bean which gets data from DB through DAO(it works on JSF+managed bean), and I want to inject that session bean with @EJB, but it returns null, am I doing something wrong?

MyRESTApplication.java:

```
public class MyRESTApplication extends Application {

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    private Set<Class<?>> empty = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    public MyRESTApplication(){
         singletons.add(new TablesResource());
    }
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
         return empty;
    }
    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
         return singletons;
    }
}
```

TablesResource.java:

```
@Path("/RESTService")
public class TablesResource {

    @EJB
    private TablesSB tablesSB;

    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    @Path("/table")
    public Tables getTable() {
        return tablesSB.getTable(28);
    }
}
```

session bean:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class TablesSB {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    private TablesDAO tablesDao;
    private TablesDAOxml tablesDaoXml;

    public TablesSB() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        //tablesDao = new TablesDAO(em);
        tablesDaoXml = new TablesDAOxml();
    }

    public Tables getTable(int tableId) {
        return tablesDaoXml.getTable(tableId);
    }
    ...
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>BarBar</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>ws.MyRESTApplication</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

stack trace:

```
20:59:06,820 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/BarBar].[Resteasy]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet Resteasy threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:149) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:372) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ws.TablesResource.getTable(TablesResource.java:30) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:280) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:234) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:221) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: there is any log at deployment time of .war file, (was the EJB deployed correctly) ?

Comment: I'm not sure, how can I check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the cause of this is because you are using RestEasy explicitly. It cannot inject the EJB because it doesn't know about it. Can you try *replacing the entire web.xml* above with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>BarBar</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>yourcompany.yourpackage.MyRESTApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

(i.e. substituted all the RestEasy stuff with the standard servlet mapping for JAX-RS - see JAX-RS 1.1 specs, ch. 2.3.2; obviously replace `yourcompany.yourpackage.MyRESTApplication` with the real fully quallified name of `MyRESTApplication`)

Alternatively, annotate your application class with `javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath` and remove all relevant configuration from web.xml:

```
@ApplicationPath("/*")
public class MyRESTApplication extends Application {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hints from Nikos are completely true. However it's strange that code works for you. 
In your code You create reference of *TablesResource* class "manually". You call constructor explicit.

```
public MyRESTApplication(){
     singletons.add(new TablesResource());
}
```

The class *MyRESTApplication* should be change as follow. The point is to show container which classes it should use. And it has to call constructor(s) itself.

```
public class MyRESTApplication extends Application {

   private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
   private Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

   public MyRESTApplication(){
        classes.add(TablesResource.class); 
        // singletons.add(new TablesResource());
   }

   @Override
   public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }

   @Override
   public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
   }
}
```

(I had similar problem and I solved it with above changes. The problem is the code automatically generated from Eclipse JBoss Tool "Create Sample RESTful Service".)

Answer (score 0):

Please add bean.xml file in WEB-INF folder and paste the below code in bean.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

</beans>
```